# cargar imagen desde formulario jsp, guardar la ruta como String en MySQL y generar vista previa en una tabla html

Tags: mysql, jsp, hibernate

Tengo un formulario que envía los datos a un servlet:

```
    <form name="altaMotorista" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="GestionMotorista?action=nuevoMotorista">

  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${motorista.id}"/><br><br>
  Nombre:<br>
  <input type="text" name="nombre" value="${motorista.nombre}"/><br><br>
  Edad:<br>
  <input type="number" name="edad" value="${motorista.edad}"/><br><br>
  Moto:<br>
  <select name="moto" value="${motorista.motocicleta}">
        <%
        if (moto.listar() !=null){
        out.print("<option value=0>Seleccione motocicleta</option>");
        for (Motocicleta m : moto.listar()){
        out.print("<option value="+m.getId()+" "+m.getMarca()+" "+m.getModelo()+" "+m.getCilindrada()+">"+m.getMarca()+" "+m.getModelo()+" "+m.getCilindrada()+"</option>");
        }
        }else out.print("<option>'No hay motocicletas regstradas'</option>");
         %>
        </select><br><br>
  Foto:<br>
  <input type="file" name="foto" value="${motorista.foto}"/><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" id="boton">
</form>
```

En el servlet, tengo un método que recoge todos los datos y los inserta en la base de datos. En la foto, me inserta el nombre del parámetro que tengo en el formulario para la foto (name= "foto"):

```
Motorista motorista= new Motorista();

            motorista.setNombre(request.getParameter("nombre"));
         motorista.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("edad")));
            motorista.setMotocicleta(request.getParameter("moto"));
            motorista.setFoto("foto");      
            motorista.insertar();
            System.out.println(motorista);
            response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

Mediante el siguiente método se imprime la tabla en el jsp con todos los registros existentes:

```
public String listado() {
    ArrayList<Motorista> motoristas = new ArrayList();
    motoristas = (ArrayList<Motorista>) DaoMotorista.listar();
    String lista = new String();
    lista = "<table cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"2\" border=\"1\"><th>Id</th><th>Nombre</th><th>Edad</th><th>Moto</th><th>Foto</th><th colspan=2>Opciones</th>";
    if (motoristas != null) {
        for (Motorista m : motoristas) {
            lista += "<tr><td>" + m.getId() + "</td><td>" + m.getNombre() + "</td><td>" + m.getEdad() + "</td><td>"
                    + m.getMotocicleta() + "</td><td>" + m.getFoto()+ "</td><td><a href='GestionMotorista?action=editar&id=" + m.getId()
                    + "'>Editar</a></td><td><a href='GestionMotorista?action=eliminar&id=" + m.getId()
                    + "'>Eliminar</a></td></tr>";
        }
    }
    return lista;
}
```

Y esta es la tabla que muestra en mi jsp:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito que en el campo foto, salga la foto en pequeño y que en la base de datos aparezca la ruta donde se ha guardado. 
Llevo todo el día dándole vueltas y no encuentro soluciones. Es necesario que la foto se guarde como String, no como BLOB.
Ayuda por favor!!!!

Answer (score 1):

La solución es la siguiente:

```
Part archivo = request.getPart("foto"); //llamada al parámetro foto de mi formulario.
String context = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("img"); //img es la carpeta que he creado en mi proyecto, dentro de la carpeta Web Content.

String foto = Paths.get(archivo.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); 


archivo.write(context + File.separator + foto); // Escribimos el archivo al disco duro del servidor.

String fotoName = UPLOAD_DIR + File.separator + foto;

motorista.setFoto(fotoName); //guardamos la ruta de la foto.
```

Este es el resultado en mi JSP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado en mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]